# How to change users vc permissions to Manage Channel [discord.py]

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I know how to change permissions in Voice channels and Text channels, yet I can't find anywhere in the documentation what they are called, so I have to randomly guess, and I just couldn't find what to use for manage channels permissions.

My code:

```
member_permissions = channel.overwrites_for(member)
member_permissions.manage = True
```

Could anyone help me with what I should replace .manage with in order to change manage channel permissions. Or if it's possible, even where I can find it in the API reference/documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
member_permissions.manage_channels = True
```

Simply that, also, it's the first result when searching for  `manage_channels` in the docs, [link here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=manage_channels#discord.Permissions.manage_channels)

Comment: Thx a lot, I believe I tried that but without the s at the end of channel and thanks for linking it in the docs :)